# How can i retrieving AUTO_INCREMENT column values through kettle batch insert?

Tags: mysql, etl, kettle

there are two table in mysql, ddl as follow

```
CREATE TABLE `class` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `class_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE student (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  class_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  student_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I need retrieving `id` after batch save `class` to batch save `student` use kettle.

Comment: Are you using InnoDB?

Comment: Also, **exactly** how are you doing batch inserts in MySQL? There are a variety of different ways, with implications on how you get `auto_increment` back out...

Comment: yes, i using innodb

Comment: I use kettle `table output` component.I don't know the way it using.

Comment: I think the point is kettle.I know how to get `auto_increment` in myself java application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it in one transformation, i.e. inserting into class table and student table at the same time, you'll need to use two transformations, first transformation inserts into class table, so you generate the id for each class name, and second transformation, after the first has finished, to perform a lookup in the class table to get the id, and afterwards inserting in the student table.

Keep in mind that in Kettle transformations initialize ALL the steps at the beginning, so you can't insert a new id and select for the new id at the same time. You could use the Block step to give time for the insertion to get committed, before querying the class table, but since it isn't something you can do at the same time, I think it becomes more clear to separate it to different transformations that are executed in order.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did it like you said.
I ask this question because i find a api named `getGeneratedKeys` in `java.sql.Statement`.

Comment: I don't know about that API in the Pentaho code, but I don't think it is used when generating IDs in the database, that piece of code would be generic or java specific, and each database handles IDs differently, so retrieving the generated ID would be something specific of the database, something in the database driver, not generic for all the databases. Pentaho transformations have a step to generate unique IDs for the stream of data, probably that API is related to that step.